# Cleaning String with Java Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string

I have a small Node Script which is web Scraping a Web Page. From that page I am extracting an array of Strings.

I am trying to clean up those Strings (currently with regex and string.replace)

One example String looks like this:

> 2  Glücklich sind die,*die seine Erinnerungen* beachten,+die mit ganzem Herzen nach ihm suchen.+\n

My cleaning code looks like this.

```
string.replace(/\+/g, '').replace(/\*/g, '').replace('\n', '').replace(/(^\d+)/g, '').trim()
```

The first section removes all "+", the second removes all *, the third removes the new Line and the last one removes the leading number.

The most things work fine but I have some edge cases.
This is my Result:

> 2  Glücklich sind die,die seine Erinnerungen beachten,die mit ganzem Herzen nach ihm suchen.

Problems:

1. The Leading Number was not removed (when the number has two or more digits it gets always removed, i have no Idea why a Single digit stays the same.)
2. The first * got removed but because there was no whitespace there is no space anymore ;(. The second * was followed by a white space... so no Problems here.
3. Same issue with the "+"... no whitespace following so the words stick together

My goal is to parse every String correctly. I have thousands of strings with different combinations but only "+", *, "\n" and the number as special characters.

The String should look like this:

> Glücklich sind die, die seine Erinnerungen beachten, die mit ganzem Herzen nach ihm suchen.

Hopefully someone has an idea to accomplish that.

Comment: The `^\d+` pattern should replace a single digit...is it possible there is leading space? Maybe try doing the `.trim()` first? Also if you know a `+/*` should always have space after being replaced, you could do this: `.replace(/\s*(\+|\*)\s*/g, ' ')`. That way any existing spaces will be removed with the `*/+` and you replace it all with a single space.

Comment: Wow super. Putting the trim first fixed the digit replacing ;). Maybe there was whitespace like you said. And no ;( a "+" is not always followed by a whitespace ;(.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an alternation `|` with a character class `[+*\n]` to match either one of the characters or 1+ digits `^\d+` at the start of the string.

```
[+*\n]|^\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5aBXZa/1)

In the replacement use a space. Afterwards, replace all the 2 or more spaces with a single space.

```js
let pattern = /[+*\n]|^\d+/g;
let string = "2  Glücklich sind die,*die seine Erinnerungen* beachten,+die mit ganzem Herzen nach ihm suchen.+\n";
string = string
  .replace(pattern, " ")
  .replace(/[ ]{2,}/g, " ")
  .trim();

console.log(string);
```

---

If the digits at the start of the string can be preceded by optional whitespace chars, you could match those as well by matching 0+ times a whitespace char except a newline `^[^\S\r\n]*\d+`

```js
let pattern = /[+*\n]|^[^\S\r\n]*\d+/g;
let string = "  2  Glücklich sind die,*die seine Erinnerungen* beachten,+die mit ganzem Herzen nach ihm suchen.+\n";
string = string
  .replace(pattern, " ")
  .replace(/[ ]{2,}/g, " ")
  .trim();

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve all your goals with a fairly short regex, and a single call to `String.prototype.replace`:

```js
let cleanStr = str => str.replace(/^[0-9\s]*|[+*\r\n]/g, '');

console.log(cleanStr('2  Glücklich sind die,die seine Erinnerungen beachten,+die mit ganzem Herzen nach ihm suchen.+\n'));
```

This regex detects either `^[0-9\s]*` or `[+*\r\n]` (and these sequences will be replaced with the empty string).

`^[0-9\s]*` replaces any number of consecutive digit or whitespace characters at the beginning of the string.

`^[+*\r\n]` removes any "+", "*", or newline characters (including `\r`, which could be significant in windows environments) which occur anywhere in the string.

Comment: Yes the replacing works, but with your solution the whitespace after the "," is missing

Comment: The input is missing the space

Comment: ohhhh ;) the char at this position is * but the markdown editor formatted the text accordingly....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```js
let str = `2  Glücklich sind die,*die seine Erinnerungen* beachten,+die mit ganzem Herzen nach ihm suchen.+\n`

str = str.replace(/[\*\+]/g," ")
         .replace(/^\d+(\s+)?/,"") // or add .trim()
         .replace(/\n?/,"")
         .replace(/\s{2,}/g," ")
console.log(str)
```